# React.js: counter function for slider component doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

this is my first project in react.js and I'm trying to create a 'slider' component for a website (with gatsby.js), which includes some content and back and forth buttons for changing the shown content by clicking them. 
For that case, I tried to implement some functionality which allows me to switch back and forth between three array objects when clicking the buttons.

It all seems to work but the counter function, which should count up and down between the range of 1 and 3 by clicking the button, doesn't work properly as it count like this:

### Console Output

```
Forth Button: 1
Forth Button: 2
Forth Button: 3
Back Button: 1
Back Button: 3
Back Button: 2
Back Button: 1
Back Button: 3
Forth Button: 2
Forth Button: 3
Forth Button: 1
```

It seems like it counts up/down one more time when clicking the opposite button, but I struggle to find out why. I guess I'm missing something obvious here.

### **The array**:

```
const slides = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Kulinarik",
    subtitle: "a look inside our kitchen",
    img: require("../../images/sliderKulinarik-2.jpg"),
    text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
      eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore...`,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Kulinarik",
    subtitle: "Buffets aus aller Welt",
    img: require("../../images/sliderKulinarik-6.jpeg"),
    text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore... `,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Kulinarik",
    subtitle: "Highlights am Buffet",
    img: require("../../images/sliderKulinarik-3.jpeg"),
    text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
      eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore ...`,
  },
]
```

### **The slider Component:**

```
const Slider = (props) => {

  const [slide, setSlide] = useState(slides[0])
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1)
  const ids = slides.map(slides => slides.id)

  const countUp = () => {
    if (counter < 3) {
      setCounter(counter + 1)
    } else if (counter === 3) {
      setCounter(1)
    }
    console.log('Forth Button: ' + counter)
  }

  const countDown = () => {
    if (counter > 1 && counter <= 3) {
      setCounter(counter -1)
    } else if ( counter === 1) {
      setCounter(3)
    }
    console.log('Back Button: ' + counter)

  }


  const changeContent = () => {
    if (counter === 1) {
      setSlide(slides[0])
    } else if (counter === 2) {
      setSlide(slides[1])
    } else if (counter === 3) {
      setSlide(slides[2])
    }
  }

  const handleRight = () => {
    countUp()
    changeContent()
  }
  const handleLeft = () => {
    countDown()
    changeContent()
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.slider}>
      <div className={styles.slider__number}>{slide.id}</div>
      <p className={styles.slider__title}>{slide.title}</p>
      <div className={styles.slider__text}>
        <h2> {slide.subtitle}</h2>
        {slide.text}
        <Link to="/" className={styles.slider__link}>
          {props.link}
        </Link>
      </div>
      <img src={slide.img} className={styles.slider__img}></img>
      <img src={arrowRight} className={styles.slider__btnRight} onClick {handleRight}></img>
      <img src={arrowLeft} className={styles.slider__btnLeft} onClick={handleLeft}></img>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Slider
```

It would be great if someone could help me out!

Comment: What are you expecting in the output, something like the following?

Forth Button: 1
Forth Button: 2
Forth Button: 3
Back Button: 3
Back Button: 2
Back Button: 1

Comment: The counter should work like this:
Forth Button: 1
Forth Button: 2
Forth Button: 3
Forth Button: 1
Forth Button: 2
Back Button: 1
Back Button: 3
Back Button: 2
Back Button: 1

Maybe you could imagine this like an 'image slider', where you can look at an image, then the next one or the previous one when clicking the corresponding button. I hope this makes it a bit better to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State updates in React are asynchronous. which means u dont know when will react to a +1 or -1 to the state. react does some optimizations in the set state like batching up the state updates etc. in your case you just have u to use state updater function

here is a [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) to the docs

state updater function
`setState((prevState)=>prevState + 1)`

```
  const [slide, setSlide] = useState(slides[0])
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1)
  const ids = slides.map(slides => slides.id)

  const countUp = () => {
    if (counter < 3) {
      setCounter(prevCounter=>prevCounter + 1)
    } else if (counter === 3) {
      setCounter(1)
    }
    console.log('Forth Button: ' + counter)
  }

  const countDown = () => {
    if (counter > 1 && counter <= 3) {
      setCounter(prevCounter=>prevCounter - 1)
    } else if ( counter === 1) {
      setCounter(3)
    }
    console.log('Back Button: ' + counter)

  }


  const changeContent = () => {
    if (counter === 1) {
      setSlide(slides[0])
    } else if (counter === 2) {
      setSlide(slides[1])
    } else if (counter === 3) {
      setSlide(slides[2])
    }
  }

  const handleRight = () => {
    countUp()
    changeContent()
  }
  const handleLeft = () => {
    countDown()
    changeContent()
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.slider}>
      <div className={styles.slider__number}>{slide.id}</div>
      <p className={styles.slider__title}>{slide.title}</p>
      <div className={styles.slider__text}>
        <h2> {slide.subtitle}</h2>
        {slide.text}
        <Link to="/" className={styles.slider__link}>
          {props.link}
        </Link>
      </div>
      <img src={slide.img} className={styles.slider__img}></img>
      <img src={arrowRight} className={styles.slider__btnRight} onClick {handleRight}></img>
      <img src={arrowLeft} className={styles.slider__btnLeft} onClick={handleLeft}></img>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Slider


  [1]: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous
```